# Use tikz to create hypercube

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is my first post here and please let me know if questions like the following are acceptable here.

I would like to draw a Hamming Cube -- the set [image] using TikZ. I also would like to draw a few chains which are ascending paths from [image] to [image] each containing n points. An illustration of what I wish to achieve is here.

I hope the picture should clarify my question.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Hypercube with a few ascending chains which might overlap]

**EDIT(Added later)**: In view of the answer provided by Gernot, I think I did not really ask a very concrete question. I would be happy to achieve the following.

I do not want to fix n -- in particular this means that we can pretend that I am happy drawing hypercube abstractly as two bell shaped curves (or Guassians) drawn vertically touching at end points. If this is too time intensive, I am also perfectly happy drawing the hypercube as 2 bent paths touching at end points as shown in my drawing.

In other words, I guess I would be satisfied if I can obtain the picture I draw using TikZ. I realize I could have asked precisely that in the first place, apologies for that.

Please let me know if the question is now clear.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you show us the code you've got? Then you can explain exactly the problem you want help with.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is highly underspecified, as the sample paths depend on what you want to exemplify. It is also not clear if you want to keep *n* undetermined or whether you want to fix *n* to some value, say 3, 4, or 5. (It might be easier to understand if the depth is fixed.)

Here are two attempts meant as starters. Once you have found out yourself where you want to put which nodes and labels and which types of lines (straight, bent, dotted, dashed, solid, ...) you need, feel free to ask specific questions on how to achieve a certain effect.

The key `tuple` defines how the nodes in the lattice are typeset, and the command `\lb` defines how the labels of nodes are typeset.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\lb[1]{\small$#1$}
  \tikzset{tuple/.style={}}
  \node[tuple] (0-0) {\lb{0\cdots0}};
  \node[tuple] (10-0) at (-2,1) {\lb{10\cdots0}};
  \node[tuple] (0-01) at ( 2,1) {\lb{0\cdots01}};
  \node[tuple] (1-10-0) at (-6,3) {\lb{1\cdots10\cdots0}};
  \node[tuple] (0-01-1) at ( 6,3) {\lb{0\cdots01\cdots1}};
  \node[tuple] (1-10) at (-2,5) {\lb{1\cdots10}};
  \node[tuple] (01-1) at ( 2,5) {\lb{01\cdots1}};
  \node[tuple] (1-1) at (0,6) {\lb{1\cdots1}};
  \draw (0-0) -- (10-0);
  \draw (0-0) -- (0-01);
  \draw[dashed] (10-0) -- (1-10-0);
  \draw[dashed] (0-01) -- (0-01-1);
  \draw[dashed] (1-10-0) -- (1-10);
  \draw[dashed] (0-01-1) -- (01-1);
  \draw (1-10) -- (1-1);
  \draw (01-1) -- (1-1);
  \draw[dotted] (10-0) -- (0-01);
  \draw[dotted] (1-10) -- (01-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\lb[1]{\small$#1$}
  \tikzset{tuple/.style={circle,draw,fill,inner sep=1pt}}
  \node[tuple,label={[below]\lb{0\cdots0}}] (0-0) {};
  \node[tuple,label={[below left]\lb{10\cdots0}}] (10-0) at (-2,1) {};
  \node[tuple,label={[below right]\lb{0\cdots01}}] (0-01) at ( 2,1) {};
  \node[tuple,label={[left]\lb{1\cdots10\cdots0}}] (1-10-0) at (-6,3) {};
  \node[tuple,label={[right]\lb{0\cdots01\cdots1}}] (0-01-1) at ( 6,3) {};
  \node[tuple,label={[above left]\lb{1\cdots10}}] (1-10) at (-2,5) {};
  \node[tuple,label={[above right]\lb{01\cdots1}}] (01-1) at ( 2,5) {};
  \node[tuple,label={[above]\lb{1\cdots1}}] (1-1) at (0,6) {};
  \draw (0-0) -- (10-0);
  \draw (0-0) -- (0-01);
  \draw[dashed] (10-0) -- (1-10-0);
  \draw[dashed] (0-01) -- (0-01-1);
  \draw[dashed] (1-10-0) -- (1-10);
  \draw[dashed] (0-01-1) -- (01-1);
  \draw (1-10) -- (1-1);
  \draw (01-1) -- (1-1);
  \draw[dotted,shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt] (10-0) -- (0-01);
  \draw[dotted,shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt] (1-10) -- (01-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Gernot. I will update the question to make it more concrete.

Comment: @gernot You are excellent for drawing.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for the flowers, but these are just a bunch of plain `\node` and `\draw` commands ...